# Laravel - Retain Value from Form Post

Tags: php, html, laravel

I currently have a drop-down box that filters data in my view. After the form posts I would like to retain the selected "publication_id" from the post so it can be used for additional filtering if needed.

Here is my current code

```
<select name="publication_id" id="publication_id" class="form-control input-sm" >
@foreach($publications as $publication)
<option value="{{ $publication->id }}" <?php if(isset($_GET['publication_id']) == '{{ $publication->id }}') echo 'selected'; ?>>{{ $publication->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

The problem is that the selected value after the post always defaults to the last option in the foreach loop from above. How can I get this working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this to generate a `select` and your old selected item will retain (`Input::old()`)

```
{{ Form::select('publication_id', $publications, Input::old('publication_id')) }}
```

Check the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists) for more details.

Comment: I've tried your method here but now after the post it is defaulting to the first value. This is the code I have in my controller. $publications = Publication::lists('name', 'id');

Comment: When you'll redirect it back on failed validation, the previously selected value will be set and at the first time it'll be the first one. Also make sure, values are mapped as `'id' => 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

The `isset()` inside your if statement will return true or false and not the `$_GET['publication_id']`.This is what is compared to the $publication->id and not actually the `$_GET['publication_id']`. You can simply use:

```
<?php if($_GET['publication_id'] == '{{ $publication->id }}') echo ' selected="selected" '; ?>
```

In your code, in case the isset() return true, this matches to every $publication->id !=0, so all your options probably have the selected attribute set.